How to allocate a pointer of functions that returns a pointer to array of n elements on C++ 20
C++ 20
I have this function:
int (*funcArrayReturn())[6];

The function returns a pointer to an array int[6] (6 elements aggregated).
And I need a pointer of pointers of n elements(in this case 3) dynamically allocated like this:
int (*(*(*funcPtr2)[3])())[6];

C++ 20
int (*funcArrayReturn())[6]
{
    int x[6];

    int (*array_matrix_allocated)[6] = new int[1][6]{ 25 };

    int number = array_matrix_allocated[0][0];
    
    number = array_matrix_allocated[0][2];

    return array_matrix_allocated;
}

I would dynamically allocate the pointer of this function with n elements
Pointer of pointers of 3 elements of functions with a return of a pointer of array int of n elements (6 in this case)
int (*(*(*funcPtr2)[3])())[6]` = new (int (*(*[10])[3]())[6]);)

(this is a wrong expression(10 elements)
Thank you

A pointer-to-function can't be dynamically allocated. Array types are not valid as a return type. Do you mean a function that returns a (pointer to a) dynamically allocated array?

Could you please state what your program is supposed to do, rather than what your attempt looks like now?
